# How to add password to a keystore file without an existing password?‏

Tags: java, android, keystore, keytool, reset-password

My Keystore file was created a long time ago, when there was an option to create a Keystore file without a password.
I am currently working on a new version and want to secure my file.
When I use keytool and try to enter the previous empty password I get an error.
The same thing happens with KeyStore Explorer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you entering your empty password using the keytool?

Comment: just ENTER  keyboard key

Comment: Can you try by providing empty password like `-storepass ''`.

Comment: gets an error:  Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: Do you remember which java version was used to create your keystore?

Comment: I can not know because I am not the developer who created the keystore